# Changing colours in whiptail

Tags: linux, bash, colors, whiptail

Is there any way to change particular colour in whiptail ?

For example to mark specific text in red ?

For example :

```
#!/bin/bash
window=$(stty -a | tr \; \\012 |egrep 'rows|columns' | cut '-d ' -f3)
RED="red"
GREEN="green"


OPTION=$(whiptail --menu "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" --title  "menu" --nocancel $window 20 \
"1" "COLOUR IS $RED" \
"2" "COLOUR IS $GREEN" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
```

How can I colour $RED and $GREEN ?

Comment: Please provided a valid `whiptail` invocation. Your example has unbalanced quotes, and `$window` is unspecified.

Comment: Thanks, $window will get the current window size from the shell , but could be also manually adjusted . Fixed the quotes .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since version 0.52.13 (released in 2011), you can use the `NEWT_COLORS` environment variable, e. g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

export NEWT_COLORS='
window=,red
border=white,red
textbox=white,red
button=black,white
'

whiptail ...
```

Alternatively, you can create a config file with your palette and reference it using the `NEWT_COLORS_FILE` variable. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/781062/400750) for more information.

The patch was originally created by the *Ubuntu* community but later [accepted](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=689903) in the upstream.

Comment: Thanks a lot that works for almost everything , but am I able to highlight text ?

Comment: @ElPopo Unfortunately, no. `dialog` has the `--colors` switch and can process embedded `\Z` sequences, but `whiptail` doesn't provide any similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks Bass , I will mark this as an answer as it is the closest solution I found so far !

Answer (score 2):

`whiptail` doesn't have relevant command-options or configuration files to change its color scheme.  You can see what it *does* by reading its source-code:

- [project page](https://pagure.io/newt)
- [whiptail program](https://pagure.io/newt/blob/master/f/whiptail.c#_360) (options table)

[`dialog`](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) does have this capability (see [screenshots](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog-figures.html#list_colors)).

Comment: Thanks , yes , right . I was hoping there is a "hack" to change the colour with whiptail... Unfortunately I can not use dialog for my project .